# SQLPlus 's weird reaction during DML statements execution

Tags: oracle10g, sqlplus

Today i was executing DML statements from sql file in sqlplus, oracle 10.2, i found something weird which is actually a question "**Enter value for hamburger:**". See attached [image]

and ending of question "Enter value for XXX" kept change with intervals. i mean after few seconds  i found statement "Enter value for mcdonald"....

I want to know is it normal with sqlplus ????

i have tried to execute DML statement by giving location of sql file in sqlplus.

**SQL>@/tmp/myDir/dmls.sql;**

An Exemplary statement from sql file  is

```
Insert into MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE (ID,DIX_DIR_ID,DIX_AGL,DIX_XML_INLINE) values (23202,1100080319000620471,'directory','<values>
 <dir_class_title>Person</dir_class_title>
</values>
');
```

Comment: What does your SQL statements look like? Can you show us the contents of dmls.sql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly have an ampersand in your statement.

When SQL*Plus encounters an ampersand, it tries to replace it with what it is defined to. If it is undefined, it prompts for a value:

This is a statment without ampersand:

```
SQL> select 'foo' from dual;
'FO
---
foo
```

Now, another statement with an ampersand. The value for `foo` is not (yet) defined, so it prompts for one:

```
SQL> select '&foo' from dual;
Enter value for foo: bla
old   1: select '&foo' from dual
new   1: select 'bla' from dual

'BL
---
bla
```

Now, `foo` is defined to be *bar*:

```
SQL> define foo=bar
```

The select statement (with `&foo`) returns *bar*:

```
SQL> select '&foo' from dual;
old   1: select '&foo' from dual
new   1: select 'bar' from dual

'BA
---
bar
```

See also [DEFINE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12017.htm) and [Defining Substitution Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch5.htm#sthref1020)

If you want to turn that behavior off, do as

```
SQL> set define off
```

**Edit**: changed `set define=` to `set define off` as per Adam Musch's suggestion.

Comment: @AdamMusch: thanks for the suggestion. I have improved my answer.